# What is difference between subset function and filter function in R?

Tags: r

When I do these two functions in R, one returns error, but one works well. Why? I think both functions return same thing.

```
impute[1,]$steps <- filter(steps_per_interval,
                           interval==impute[1,]$interval)[,2]
```

> Error: invalid subscript type 'integer'

```
impute[1,]$steps <- subset(steps_per_interval, 
                           interval==impute[1,]$interval)[,2]
```

Comment: We need to see more of what you're using. Is this `dplyr::filter`? Your code is not reproducible.

Comment: Finn-ally someone spoke the truth. Now your next question should be "*what's the difference between `transform` and `mutate`*", we will get there eventually I believe.

Comment: Not a `dplyr` fan, eh @DavidArenburg? :-)

Comment: Not a fan of assuming that `filter` comes from pkg:dplyr  when a function of the same name already exists in pkg:stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm correct, but seems like inside filter you can't make a reference combining `$` and `[]` in the same expression as in `interval==impute[1,]$interval`. Instead you could try:

```
x < -which(colnames(impute)=="interval")

library(dplyr)
impute[1,]$steps <- filter(steps_per_interval,
                       interval==impute[1,x])[,2]
```